# What's the difference between: os.listdir('.') vs os.listdir()

Tags: python, directory

For the os library what is the difference between

os.listdir('.') vs os.listdir()

They both seem to produce the same results (a list of everything in the active directory) however:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

says that os.listdir specifically excludes '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

There is no functional difference, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).  The definition of `os.listdir()` looks like this

```
os.listdir(path='.')
```

So the default value for path when you call `os.listdir()` is `'.'`

Answer (score 2):

From `help os.listdir`:

```
listdir(path=None)
    Return a list containing the names of the files in the directory.

    path can be specified as either str or bytes.  If path is bytes,
      the filenames returned will also be bytes; in all other circumstances
      the filenames returned will be str.
    If path is None, uses the path='.'.
```

That is, `os.listdir()` is the same as `os.listdir('.')`.

> [...] says that `os.listdir` specifically excludes '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory. What does that mean?

That concerns the returned values.
In UNIX filesystems, every directory has `.` and `..` entries,
where `.` refers to the current directory,
and `..` to the parent directory.
The documentation says that these entries will not be included in the list returned by `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 0):

**.**[dot] in listdir() refers to current directory & when we do not provide any input to listdir() then by default it lists current directory that's the reason it shows same result.